# how to use ant script to create directory and set last modified date

Tags: ant, directory, mkdir, dir, last-modified

Is there any way I can recursively create a directory and set the last modified date of each directory ????

For example, we create `/testparent/testdir/test/` directory, and we want to set the last modified date to all the child directory.

```
/testparent/                last modified date 2012/01/01
/testparent/testdir/        last modified date 2012/01/01
/testparent/testdir/test/   last modified date 2012/01/01
```

Comment: You can create the directories with the [`<mkdir>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mkdir.html).

Comment: Use [`<touch>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) with a nested `<fileset>` to change the last-modified dates of the directories.